# Can we use google cloud storage as database?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Google drive is technically based on google cloud storage.
and they have this API (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata) and this API (https://developers.google.com/realtime/overview ~which had been deprecated) for developers, so that we can use google drive as our mobile or web app database.

The question is, since google cloud storage and google drive are the same, can we use google cloud storage as database?
i.e creating a file in google cloud storage and use it for Create, Read, Update and Delete operation (the typical one).

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage and Google Drive are not the same, nor is one based on the other. They are entirely separate products.

You can use the Google Cloud Storage API to create Cloud Storage objects, and you can use the Google Drive API to create Google Drive objects. I'm not sure about the Realtime API, but as it's being turned down, I wouldn't advise making use of it.

The successor to that API, Cloud Firestore, is a good choice, and Firebase's cloud storage is built on top of Google Cloud Storage.